# How Do I Check Which PIP packages were installed by me and which came by defualt

Tags: python, pip, default

I did the `pip list` command in the command prompt.
This was the output:

```
Package            Version
------------------ ---------
certifi            2021.10.8
charset-normalizer 2.0.7
idna               3.3
pip                21.3.1
pygame             2.1.0
requests           2.26.0
setuptools         57.4.0
urllib3            1.26.7
```

How do I check which of these I downloaded so I can uninstall them if I wish, and how to check which came by default with python?

Comment: `How do I check which of these I downloaded so I can uninstall them if I wish` that's why we should use `virtualenv` while doing development. https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: by default came built-in modules which you can't see on this list. Other modules can be installed later (even `pip`) but some of them better don't unistall - on this list I would unistanll only `pygame` - rest modules can be used by `pip` to install other modules.